# Individual settings for caches created by @Cacheable

Tags: spring, caching, caffeine

So Spring decided to drop Guava and introduce Caffeine cache support instead. I have the feeling that the support is very limited.

The easiest way to use a cache is with the @Cacheable annotation. A quite common use case is for sure to have multiple caches which have different settings (e.g. long/short lived).

I wasn't able to figure out how to do this. In fact I think it is not possible with the current implementation and this really surprises me.

`CaffeineCacheManager` is used by Spring to dynamically create caches. It has a few methods to set a `Caffeine`, a `CacheLoader` or a `CaffeineSpec` where you can set the cache properties. However, this is then used for all created caches and I didn't see a way to have properties set for only one cache.

Did I miss anything here?

Comment: That’s how their guava integration worked, so it a minor change to switch over. A richer adapter is provided by https://github.com/stepio/coffee-boots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this now. And i created an issue to make this easier [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25230)

```java
public class CustomCaffeineCacheManager extends CaffeineCacheManager {

    private Map<String, Cache> preDefinedCaches = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void addCache(String name, Cache cache) {
        preDefinedCaches.put(name, cache);
    }

    @Override
    protected Cache<Object, Object> createNativeCaffeineCache(String name) {
        return preDefinedCaches.getOrDefault(name, super.createNativeCaffeineCache(name));
    }
}
```

In @Configuration class:

```java
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    CustomCaffeineCacheManager caffeineCacheManager = new CustomCaffeineCacheManager();
    caffeineCacheManager.addCache("customCache", Caffeine.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterWrite(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .maximumSize(5_000).build());
    return caffeineCacheManager;
}
```